# Extracting an archive with progress bar - mutable borrow error

Tags: file, rust, borrowing

I am trying to extract a .tar.bz file (or .tar.whatever actually) and also be able to have a xx% progress report. So far I have this:

```
pub fn extract_file_with_progress<P: AsRef<Path>>(&self, path: P) -> Result<()> {
    let path = path.as_ref();
    let size = fs::metadata(path)?;
    let mut f = File::open(path)?;
    let decoder = BzDecoder::new(&f);
    let mut archive = Archive::new(decoder);

    for entry in archive.entries()? {
        entry?.unpack_in(".")?;
        let pos = f.seek(SeekFrom::Current(0))?;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

The idea is to use `pos/size` to get the percentage, but compiling the above function gets me the error `cannot borrow f as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable`.
I understand what the error means, but I don't really use `f` as mutable; I only use the seek function to get the current position.

Is there a way to work-around this, either by forcing the compiler to ignore the mutable borrow or by getting the position in some immutable way?

Comment: `seek()` takes `&mut self`, so this is where the mutable borrow happens. Looking at the crate docs, couldn't you use `decoder.total_in()` instead?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Sepcifically, we cannot tell where `BzDecoder` and `Archive` come from, plus some other traits. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Files are a bit special. The usual `read()` and `seek()` and `write()` methods (defined on the `Read`, `Seek` and `Write` traits) take `self` by mutable reference:

```
fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize>
fn seek(&mut self, pos: SeekFrom) -> Result<u64>
fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<usize>
```

However, all mentioned traits are also implemented for `&File`, i.e. for *immutable* references to a file:

- [`impl<'a> Read for &'a File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl-Read-1)
- [`impl<'a> Seek for &'a File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl-Seek-1)
- [`impl<'a> Write for &'a File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl-Write-1)

So you can modify a file even if you only have a read-only reference to the file. For these implementations, the `Self` type is `&File`, so accepting `self` by mutable reference in fact means accepting a `&mut &File`, a mutable reference to a reference to a file.

Your code passes `&f` to `BzDecoder::new()`, creating an immutable borrow. Later you call `f.seek(SeekFrom::Current(0))`, which passes `f` to `seek` by mutable reference.  However, this is not allowed, since you already have an immutable borrow of the file. The solution is to use the `Seek` implementation on `&File` instead:

```
(&mut &f).seek(SeekFrom::Current(0))
```

or slightly simpler

```
(&f).seek(SeekFrom::Current(0))
```

This only creates a second immutable borrow, which is allowed by Rust's rules for references.

I created a [playground example demonstrating that this works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=dc89b3f30ced58231066e36444a50a13). If you replace `(&f)` with `f` you get the error you originally got.

Comment: Nice one thanks. I didn't know about the &File traits implementation. But how does the `(&f).seek()` version work? Shouldn't the pointer be mutable according to the trait?

Comment: See also: [Why is it possible to implement Read on an immutable reference to File?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31503488/155423).

Comment: @thanasis2028 `(&f).seek()` works for exactly the same reason that `f.seek()` works.  Methods are first looked up on the type of the receiver itselt, say `T`, then on `&T`, then on `&mut T`, then on objects obtained by iteratively dereferencing the receiver.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52534876/279627) for further details.