# How do you call future::select on a Future stored in a struct from a method that takes &mut self?

Tags: rust, future, ownership

I want to store a future that we occasionally await in a struct. My use-case is to have a signal to tell my network packet handler to shut down gracefully. A minimal example could look like this, with a dependency on futures 0.3:

```
use futures::{
    executor::block_on,
    future::{pending, select, Either, Future},
}; // 0.3.4

struct Foo<F: Future + Unpin> {
    fut: F,
    fut_opt: Option<F>,
}

impl<F: Future + Unpin> Foo<F> {
    async fn wait(self: &mut Self) {
        let bar = pending::<&str>();
        match select(self.fut, bar).await {
            Either::Left(_) => println!("foo"),
            Either::Right(_) => println!("bar"),
        }
    }

    async fn wait_optional(self: &mut Self) {
        let bar = pending::<&str>();
        if let Some(foo) = self.fut_opt.take() {
            match select(foo, bar).await {
                Either::Left(_) => println!("foo"),
                Either::Right((_, foo_fut)) => {
                    self.fut_opt.replace(foo_fut);
                    println!("bar")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo {
        fut: pending::<()>(),
        fut_opt: Option::from(pending::<()>()),
    };

    block_on(foo.wait())
}
```

The problem is that `select` wants to move the value in the `fn wait(..)` version, so I'm getting a compile error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.fut` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/main.rs:14:22
   |
14 |         match select(self.fut, bar).await {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.fut` has type `F`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

A workaround I came up with can be seen in `fn wait_optional`: I'm (ab)using an `Option` to store the future, take it out when needed and then put it back in as `select` returns the unawaited future in `Either`. This compiles and seems to work just fine - but it feels hacky. Is there a "proper" way for achieving this?

Comment: `self: &mut Self` is non-idiomatic. `&mut self` is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a mutable reference to the future:

```rust
use futures::{
    executor::block_on,
    future::{pending, select, Either, Future},
}; // 0.3.4

struct Foo<F: Future + Unpin> {
    fut: F,
}

impl<F: Future + Unpin> Foo<F> {
    async fn wait(&mut self) {
        let bar = pending::<&str>();
        match select(&mut self.fut, bar).await {
            Either::Left(_) => println!("foo"),
            Either::Right(_) => println!("bar"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo {
        fut: pending::<()>(),
    };

    block_on(foo.wait())
}
```

This is because `Future` is [implemented for any mutable reference to a `Future`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html#implementors) with certain restrictions:

```
impl<'_, F> Future for &'_ mut F
where
    F: Unpin + Future + ?Sized,
```

See also:

- [Why does Iterator::take_while take ownership of the iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31374051/155423)
- [Why does the usage of by_ref().take() differ between the Iterator and Read traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52515361/155423)
- [Using the same iterator multiple times in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23969191/155423)
- [Cannot move out of borrowed content when trying to transfer ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28258548/155423)
- [Cannot move out of borrowed content / cannot move out of behind a shared reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28158738/155423)
- [Temporarily move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29570781/155423)
- [How do I move out of a struct field that is an Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52031002/155423)