# How can I await on HashMap future values in rust?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I'm trying to kick off some async tasks in rust, then await them later in the code. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
async fn my_async_fn() -> i64 {
  return 0;
}

async fn main() {
  let mut futures = HashMap::new();
  futures.insert("a", my_async_fn());
  // this is where I would do other work not blocked by these futures
  let res_a = futures.get("a").expect("unreachable").await;
  println!("my result: {}", res_a);
}
```

But when I try to run this, I get this self-contradictory message:

```
error[E0277]: `&impl futures::Future` is not a future
   --> my/code:a:b
    |
111 |   let res_a = futures.get("a").expect("unreachable").await;
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `&impl futures::Future` is not a future
    |
    = help: the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `&impl futures::Future`
    = note: required by `futures::Future::poll`
```

How can I await futures that I've put into a HashMap? Or is there another way altogether?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you call future::select on a Future stored in a struct from a method that takes &mut self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60515999/how-do-you-call-futureselect-on-a-future-stored-in-a-struct-from-a-method-that)

Comment: Awaiting a future requires a mutable reference, not an immutable reference.

Comment: Also note that you will almost certainly want to _box_ your futures before you insert them into the `HashMap`. As written, your `HashMap` will only ever accept futures produced by calling `my_async_fn()`, which was probably not what you intended.

Comment: @E_net4saysdon'tcopythat - it doesn't quite answer my question, but gives me a more complicated error message that `Unpin` is not implemented for `from_generator::GenFuture...`

Comment: I said that having a mutable reference was a requirement, not a sufficient condition. The `Unpin` constraint is mentioned in the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `await` requires the `Future` is pinned and mutable.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

async fn my_async_fn() -> i64 {
    return 0;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut futures = HashMap::new();
    futures.insert("a", Box::pin(my_async_fn()));
    // this is where I would do other work not blocked by these futures
    let res_a = futures.get_mut("a").expect("unreachable").await;
    println!("my result: {}", res_a);
}
```

Comment: This, of course, does not work with closure and async closures are not stable yet.